# J verb or phrase to group together runs of identical elements

Tags: j

This is best demonstrated by example:

Input:

```
1 2 2 1 1 1 2 3 3
```

Output:

```
    1; 2 2; 1 1 1; 2; 3 3

┌─┬───┬─────┬─┬───┐
│1│2 2 │1 1 1│2│3 3│
└─┴───┴─────┴─┴───┘
```

So I'm looking for something like Key `/.`, but Key would group *all* ones together, *all* twos together, and so on.  I want to group only contiguous runs together.

One final thought: Key can be used successfully, if I can first generate an `x` for it that looks like this:

```
0 1 1 2 2 2 3 4 4   NB. x suitable for use in Key
1 2 2 1 1 1 2 3 3   NB. original data
```

I cannot think of a tacit solution for generating such an x, though (my ideas involve a mutating temporary variable to store the current "label", ie, the numbers 0 through 4 in the `x` defined above)

Comment: Is `x =. +/\ 0 , (}. ~: }:) set` what you're looking for? Or are you saying that you can already do that, but are hoping for something more elegant?

Comment: `make_x =. [: +/\ 0 , }. ~: }:`

Comment: @Dane, that's quite nice.  I was _hoping_ (though not expecting) for something builtin, or perhaps an adverb, but I'll accept that as an answer.  Thanks.

Comment: Key ``/.`` is able to perform this too (``</.~1+/\@,}:~:}.``), however the proper primitive to use is Cut, specifically, ``;.1``.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An alternative to Key `/.` in this case is dyadic [Cut](http://code.jsoftware.com/wiki/Vocabulary/semidot1#dyadic) `;.` :

Build `x` as:

```
   (1 ,~ 2 ~:/\ ]) 1 2 2 1 1 1 2 3 3
1 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 1
```

The ones mark the end of the groups. Then use dyadic `<;.2` to box those groups:

```
   ((1 ,~ 2 ~:/\ ]) <;.2 ]) 1 2 2 1 1 1 2 3 3
┌─┬───┬─────┬─┬───┐
│1│2 2│1 1 1│2│3 3│
└─┴───┴─────┴─┴───┘
```

This can be abbreviated as:

```
   (<;.2~ 1 ,~ 2&(~:/\)) 1 2 2 1 1 1 2 3 3
┌─┬───┬─────┬─┬───┐
│1│2 2│1 1 1│2│3 3│
└─┴───┴─────┴─┴───┘
```

Comment: I _knew_ there was primitive for this.  Thank you!

Comment: Use `<;.1` and save a character :)

Comment: Yes, I wasn't sure whether to add both that option and how to use key to do the same thing.